# Обеспечить обращение к сайту только по ЧПУ

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу

Пытаюсь настроить ЧПУ.

Вот так выглядит .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?c=$0 [QSA]


<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "index.(php)$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

В файле index.php URL разбивается по слешу. И в зависимости от того, что у нас в URL, подключается нужный контроллер. Всё работает нормально.

Но есть одна проблема. При обращении по адресу site.ru/index.php открывается главная страница. При обращении по адресу site.ru/index.php?c=add открывается то же, что открывается по адресу site.ru/add.

Как сделать так, чтобы сайт работал только на ЧПУ, а при обращении по адресу типа site.ru/index.php... была ошибка 404, либо редирект на главную страницу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил проблему.**

В index.php дописал следующие строчки:

```
//Настройка 404 ошибки для 'index', 'index.php?...' и т. п. ;
$root = '/site.ru';
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pattern = "/index/i";
preg_match($pattern, $request_uri, $p_m);

if (count($p_m) > 0) {
    //Подключаем контроллер 404 ошибки, в нём есть строчка "header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 404 Not Found");"
    require_once ('c/404.php');
    exit();
}
```

Теперь работает как надо.